# Knockout.JS onSelect Binding

Tags: knockout.js

I have searched a way to give knockout an "onSelect" binding that will fire when an option is selected from a select menu.

```
 <select id="selectturf" data-bind="onSelect: function () { alert('hi') }">
                    <option>Select Assigned Turf</option>
                    <option>Example Turf</option>
  </select>
```

I'd like something similar to what I have above...

I know I could put the screen in the onselect="", but I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want already exists. It is the `event` binding and you can use it like this:

```
<select id="selectturf" data-bind="event: { 'change': function () { alert('hi'); } }">
    <option>Select Assigned Turf</option>
    <option>Example Turf</option>
</select>
```

Edit: I made you a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atp4t/1/) just in case you have trouble with it.

Also, take a look at the [documentation of `event`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) on KnockoutJS' website.